# Duplicate Data Fetch - Xamarin Firebase

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a chat application that i am implementing on my app. I am able to see chats from all users but i don't really know why my application is fetching duplicate chat when i try update using onDataChange. When i click on my button to send a chat, the fetch doesn't produce the duplicate onDataChange but when i move from a different activity into the chat activity, that is when the fetch produces the duplicates

What am i doing wrong?

For example

```
Hi  - 6.30pm

How are you 6.30pm

//duplicate on list view

Hi - 6.30pm

How are you - 6.30pm
```

Here is my code

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

        button.Click += delegate {

            PostMessage();
        };

        if(FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser == null){

            StartActivityForResult(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity)), MyResultCode);

        }

        else{
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome" +FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.DisplayName, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            DisplayChatMessages();
        }
    }

    private async void PostMessage()
    {
        var items = await firebase.Child("").PostAsync(new MessageContent(FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.DisplayName, edtChat.Text));
        edtChat.Text = "";

    }

    public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {

    }

    public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        DisplayChatMessages();
    }

    private async void DisplayChatMessages()
    {
        lstMessage.Clear();
        var items = await firebase.Child("").OnceAsync<MessageContent>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        lstMessage.Add(item.Object);
        ChatViewAdapter adapter = new ChatViewAdapter(this, lstMessage);
        lstChat.Adapter = adapter;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where is the `onDataChange` get called? Could you please post the full codes of the activity?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT That is actually my full code.  Where onDataChange gets called? If i get you right, it gets called only if there is a change in the database and it works fine. When i change data in my database, it updates the chat and this time it doesn't update with duplicates